# Displaying table containing dates and other records

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, date

I want to display all data entry in a particular table (overtime) which has 3 columns (date, number and comments). I want to sum up all numbers in Week 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Date          Number    Comments

01-07-2015      9
02-07-2015      0
03-07-2015     10
04-07-2015      8

### **27**

05-07-2015      8
06-07-2015      8
07-07-2015      9
08-07-2015      10
09-07-2015      8
10-07-2015      0
11-07-2015      0

### **43**

12-07-2015      8
13-07-2015      8
14-07-2015      9
15-07-2015      10
16-07-2015      8
17-07-2015      0
18-07-2015      0

### **43**

Below is a snippet of my code. Please, where do I incorporate your
code?

```
$query="SELECT name, timestamp, number, comment FROM table WHERE
name = '$valid_user' and timestamp between '$start_date' and '$end_date'"; 
$params = array($_REQUEST['query']); 
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);

echo "<p><table id='t01' border='1'>

<th style='width: 10px'>Date </th> 
<th style='width: 5px'>Number</th>
<th style='width: 100px'>Comment</th> 

</tr>";

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  {    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><a href=#.php?id='.strip_tags($row['id']).'>'  . date( 'd M Y', strtotime(strip_tags($row['timestamp']))). "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . strip_tags($row['number']). "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . strip_tags($row['comment']). "</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="#.php?id=' . strip_tags($row['id']). '">Edit/Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tr>";         }
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the template you can use to group by weeks:

```
DECLARE 
  @Year int = 2015,
  @Month int = 7

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = dateadd(mm, (@Year - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1, 0)
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = dateadd(mm, (@Year - 1900) * 12 + @Month, -1)

;WITH tally AS (
    SELECT (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0))) - 1 AS N
    FROM master.dbo.syscolumns sc1)
SELECT 
    --d,
    wknr
FROM 
    tally
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT 
            d = DATEADD(DAY, N, @StartDate),
            wknr = DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(DAY, N, @StartDate))) dates
WHERE d < @EndDate
GROUP BY wknr
ORDER BY wknr
```

**Edit**

I suggest you to tailor the provided query template according to your need. I see in your PHP code you need fields `name, timestamp, number, comment`, so the query should probably return them.

Next step would be to replace your old query with the new one. Pass date parameters accordingly.

I guess you can use something like:

```
;WITH tally AS (
    SELECT (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0))) - 1 AS N
    FROM master.dbo.syscolumns sc1)
SELECT 
    wknr,
    number = SUM(t.number)
FROM 
    tally
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT 
            d = DATEADD(DAY, N, @StartDate),
            wknr = DATEPART(wk, DATEADD(DAY, N, @StartDate))) dates
    JOIN table t
        ON t.timestamp = d
WHERE d < @EndDate
GROUP BY wknr
ORDER BY wknr
```

Comment: Thanks @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric for you help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: On SO you are encouraged to describe your problem in the question body. If you have problems with using the provided answer, maybe it would be best to update the question with additional details. If that would completely change the question, you should open another question for that.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, #OzrenTkalcecKrznaric. I made changes to my question by adding my code snippets.

Comment: Thanks @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric. I will give it a try and update you.

Comment: I'm totally lost on how to edit your query to meet my needs. I'm pretty new to this and your code seems quite advanced. I was wondering whether to replace my entire 'select' query with yours? 

Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Well, feel free to upvote the answer if it helps... or mark as a solution if it solves the problem described...

Comment: Hi @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric, thanks for your help. I still haven't achieved the results I want yet. So, all I want is that, I want to display all data entry in a particular table (overtime) which has 3 columns (date, number and comments). I want to sum up all numbers in Week 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. You would like to display your data in particular way. However, your initial question was how to calculate the table. The query provided in solution will calculate data, but it won't help you display this kind of data. To display it, you have to make changes in PHP. Have you tried changing the code to adapt for new data structure?

Comment: I adjusted the query you gave me to suit my needs but to no avail. I have rewritten my codes and still no results